# PHP rename file to this sql id

Tags: php, mysql, rename, mysql-insert-id

I have the following lines of php code which should rename a file which already exists on the server to the id generated in the last query:

```
$image1Oldname = "images/" . $myfile;
$image1NewName = "images/" . mysql_insert_id() . ".jpg";

rename($image1Oldname, $image1NewName);
```

For some reason this does not rename the file when the script is run.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `echo "$image1Oldname $image1NewName";`

Comment: Ah! thanks... that highlighted the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions?

Sure.
You have to learn how to debug your code.

It is not a rocket science though.

- Just turn all possible error reporting on
- and echo out every piece of data you are using to see if something goes wrong.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$image1Oldname = "images/" . $myfile;
$image1NewName = "images/" . mysql_insert_id() . ".jpg";

var_dump($image1Oldname, $image1NewName);
rename($image1Oldname, $image1NewName);
exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked that you (your PHP daemon that is) have permission to rename it, and that the path is correct?

Comment: guesswork is not the way to go. Every newbie PHP consumer have to learn that.

Comment: If i hard code it in rather than using the variables it works ok, so i definitely have permission - `rename("images/original.jpg", "images/new.jpg");`

Comment: Then your path are probably wrong somehow. Try to echo out $image1Oldname and $image1NewName. And post what it says is in there.

Comment: does $myFile have extension? or is it just name?